# Is there any ad-hoc way to prevent Visual Studio load last solution, even if configured to do it?

Tags: visual-studio

**Context**

For a long period, I configured my VS to start, then do nothing. Because I usually work on the very same solution, it took always an extra step to open the solution, so I had to wait twice, first to start, then interact, then wait to load.

I decided to configure VS load last solution when starting. This case I have to wait only once (longer of course)

**Issue to solve**

As Murphy's law dictates, now I notice, that many times I would like to work on an other solution. So I have to wait while VS loads my last solution (UI is unresponsible ), and only after then can I open the other. (familiar?)

**Question**

Is there any trick to prevent VS to load last solution, even it configured to do it?

Comment: How about creating a shortcut to that specific solution file instead, and configuring Visual Studio to *not* load the last solution upon load? Also, if you kept the startup screen it should list the solutions you work on there, you can pin the ones you use the most and just pick one from that list after starting Visual Studio. I do not know of any trick, like a command line parameter, that disables this per-instance.

Comment: Many thanks, this makes sense